# Ubuntu 18.04 Becomes Unresponsive Requiring Hard-Reboot

Tags: system

I’ve read just about everything I can find here and elsewhere about this problem but nothing seems to solve it on any of my Ubuntu systems. A laptop and three PCs of different manufacturers and chipsets have the same issue. Some are worse than others with two requiring a hard-reboot and the others, after a while, will sometime start working again. Years in the past I’ve seen this happen when the CPU overheats but that is not happening here and started only after installing Ubuntu 17.10. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe high cpu usage?
Logs will be in the /var/logs location. Open a terminal and use the command:
`ls -ltra /var/logs` which will give you the latest modification as last file of the list Try checking the system logs with:
`less /var/logs/syslog` You can also log in as command line user doing <kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> and then look for your consuming process with `top` or `sudo iotop` if the disk is the reason... **Note:** for the use of less type `man less`

Comment: If often starts hanging during boot before I’ve even opened anything and on four different PCs, I can’t imagine every one having excessive CPU usage. I’ll fetch and append the logs from the worst one and the one I need to use most often to my question. Incidentally, at least two of these are fresh installs.

Comment: Got an error but see that the correct path is /var/log so will try again.

Comment: The log is huge so should I post it above or is there something specific to look for?

Comment: Before anything, have you been using the same ubuntu iso image for the installations? Try a fresh new download, reinstall then try again. If it continues, try to have the time where you boot up and post the logs from the same time. If you have a usb, paste the log files there. While in recovery mode, plug it in and run: "sudo fdisk -l" and find where your usb. If its in /dev/sdb then mount the usb with "sudo mount -o rw /dev/sdb1 /media" and paste the log file with "cat /var/logs/syslog > /media/log.txt"

Comment: Each were each installed from a fresh ISO burned to a fresh DVD as one is in another town and another is even in a different state. As mention and as I see reported by countless others, this seems to have started with 17.10. Since the current and most problematic one is where I am doing my main work, unfortunately yet another install is not possible. Sometimes I can get a few hours or even a couple days work done, then I need to reboot over and over to get it working again which is very disruptive. I’ve been using Linux for decades but never such a perplexing and persistent problem before.

Comment: One thing I’m not sure of is if the entire PC is becoming unresponsive or if it’s only the mouse and keyboard. If the latter, it seems odd that all four PCs suddenly started having the problem more or less at the same time after an update or fresh install. On my previous comment, I meant that all that were freshly installed each used a fresh download and newly-burned disk. At least one was an update from an earlier version installed live but the one I’m using now is a fresh install and is kept up to date.

Comment: While writing the last comment on my iPad, found the PC was completely unresponsive when I went back to it! Tried another mouse but it made no difference so it’s apparently the PC that is locking up, not just an unresponsive mouse.

Comment: I suspect that there is a kernel bug of some sort as this started in v17.10. Not sure how to test by reverting to v17.04 or earlier kernel and as it is, I cannot do any work on any of four 18.04 PCs.  Until it’s been fixed, they are all useless. Sometimes they’ll work for a couple hours or on odd occasions for a couple days then without warning, become unresponsive. Totally different hardware between them so no commonality there.